# Null pointer errors when using fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

The `GPS` class and `MainActivity` both worked fine until we tried to add a second page. We've tried using intents and fragments and have spent way too many hours/days on trying to figure this out.

We keep getting `NullPointerException`s for either the `onClickListener()` in `MainActivity` and when updating any `textview`s from the `GPS` class. We know it has something to do with how the fragments work but we're not sure how to fix this.

This is our MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// Get buttons and text fields
public Button showLocation;

// TextViews
public static TextView showLatitude;
public static TextView showLongitude;  
public static TextView showDistance;

// GPS class
GPS gps;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
        }


    showLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    showLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
    showLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);
    showDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayDistance);

    // Create gps
    gps = new GPS(MainActivity.this);

    // show location button click event
    showLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {       
            gps.setTotalDistance(0.0);
        }
    });//END LISTENER  


}// END ONCREATE

public void nextPage(View view) {

    // In response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResourcePage.class);

    // Set activity intent
    startActivity(intent);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }
  }  
}
```

And this is the GPS class

```
public class GPS extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// Flag for GPS/Network/Location status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;

// Location Class
Location location; 

// Latitude and longitude save points
private double startLatitude = 0;
private double endLatitude = 1.0; 
private double startLongitude = 0;
private double endLongitude = 1.0;
private double totalDistance = 0;

// Results Array
private float[] results = new float[1];


// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // 1 second

// Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;


// Interface
public GPS(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // Getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        // Checking Flags
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // ^no network provider is enabled do nothing/go on^
        } 
        else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


                    if (location != null) {
                        startLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        startLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                    } //END OF LAST IF BLOCK
                } //END OF SECOND IF BLOCK
            } //END OF "FIRST" IF BLOCK


            // if GPS Enabled get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            startLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                            startLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }//END OF ELSE BLOCK

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

// Call to remove updates from listener
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPS.this);
    }      
}

public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        startLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // Return latitude
    return startLatitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        startLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // Return longitude
    return startLongitude;
}

//Function to check GPS/wifi are enabled
public boolean canGetLocation() {
     //return boolean
    return this.canGetLocation;
}


// Function to show settings alert dialog if gps is off
public void showSettingsAlert(){

     // On pressing Settings button will launch Settings Options
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // Settings button listener/press
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


// Called from listener on gps change of X
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //Display Latitude and Longitude
    if(location != null){
        startLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        startLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    MainActivity.showLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(startLatitude));
    MainActivity.showLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(startLongitude));

    }

    // Get distance between
    Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude,endLongitude,  results);

    // Convert to miles Add distance to total
    totalDistance = totalDistance + results[0] * 0.000621371192;

    // Display the total
    MainActivity.showDistance.setText(String.format("%.2f", totalDistance));

    // Move old values to End locations
    endLatitude = startLatitude;
    endLongitude = startLongitude;  

}

// Function to clear total distance (Testing)
public void setTotalDistance(Double savedData){

    totalDistance = savedData; 
    MainActivity.showDistance.setText(String.valueOf(totalDistance));
}

public double getTotalDistance(){

    return totalDistance;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

For the `layout` files we have `activity_main.xml` which is empty, `fragment_main.xml` which has all our text fields and `button`s and then `fragment_resource.xml` which has nothing but a `textview` so we knew things would appear on it.

Comment: if you have the views in `fragment_main.xml` why have you initialized views in Activity instead of Fragment??

Comment: post your stack trace here!!!

Comment: Your stack trace wouldn't happen to contain almost only fragment transaction related stuff and no mention of your code? If that's the case I'm not surprised, but maybe I'm off and there's multiple things wrong. In any case, you need to provide your full stack trace as well as your layout files. That will produce better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you say all your views belong to the fragment then initialize views in fragment not in Activity.

The Activity layout does not have the views and `findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout. So the initialization fails leading to `NullPointerException` when you use the view objects.

```
   TextView showLatitude;
   TextView showLongitude;  
   TextView showDistance;
   GPS gps;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
         showLocation = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
         showLatitude = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
         showLongitude = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);
         showDistance = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayDistance);
         gps = new GPS(getActivity()); // wrong bind the service to the activtiy

         showLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {       
              gps.setTotalDistance(0.0); // remove this
              }
        });
        return rootView;

    }
```

Also you have

```
public class GPS extends Service
```

Its a Service class. You need to bind the service to Activity. But you do`gps = new GPS(getActivity());`

Comment: I have a doubt do i need to remove from `android:onClick="nextPage"` from `Button`.

Comment: @Hariharan no need for that. The onClick could be for a different view also

Comment: Thanks for the help!! We've added your code in and got some errors with onCreateView, we changed mainActivity to extend fragment which cleared it up (Was that right?) Now we just get a class cast exception when we launch, might this have something to do with the manifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

By:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have the problem in this method

```
public void setTotalDistance(Double savedData){
    totalDistance = savedData; 
    MainActivity.showDistance.setText(String.valueOf(totalDistance));
}
```

> You can't just call the MainActivity that way it will return NULL
>   Pointer exception for showDistance Variable.Because its not a static
>   class.So you want to do like this.

```
public void setTotalDistance(Double savedData){

    totalDistance = savedData; 
    ((this.mContext)MainActivity).showDistance.setText(String.valueOf(totalDistance));
}
```

Surely this will make some sense.